# Inverse Laplace transform

Tags: integral-transforms

For this expression:  $ (1 - Exp[-Sqrt[1+s] x])/(1+s)$

How to make the Inverse Laplace Transform analytically?

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[(1 - Exp[-Sqrt[1+s] x])/(1+s),s,t] does not directly give solution
```

Comment: Unfortunately, InverseLaplaceTransform[(1 - Exp[-Sqrt[1 + s] x])/(1 + s), s, t,  Assumptions -> x > 0] does not work.

Comment: Mathematica 13.3 gives answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a mathematician so this may be "smoke and mirrors."

You are looking for the inverse Laplace transform of

```
g[s_] = (1 - Exp[-Sqrt[1 + s] x])/(1 + s);
```

Looking at the simpler problem

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[g[s - 1], s, t] // Simplify[#, x > 0] &
```

> 1 - Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[t])]

With x > 0, let

```
f[t_] = E^-t (1 - Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[t])]);

g[s] == LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, s] // Simplify[#, x > 0] &
```

> True

So f[t] is the inverse Laplace transform of g[s]

Comment: Your answer is correct. Verified it with Maple. Screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lBEJ9.png) the command is: `inttrans[invlaplace](  (1- exp(-sqrt(1+s)*x))/(1+s),s,t) assuming positive;` note that Maple can do it directly, just needed assumption on x>0