# How to find the Inverse Laplace transform of $Exp[(1-s)(1+1/s)]$?

Tags: special-functions, integral-transforms

How do i find the inverse laplace transform of following function:

```
f[s]=Exp[(1-s)(1+1/s)]
```

Mathematica returns exactly the simplified function without computing it.

Comment: What is this 3 in title?

Comment: @MMM Maybe to distinguish it from [50862](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50862/inverse-laplace-transform?rq=1) and [102042](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102042/inverse-laplace-transform)?

Comment: @QuantumDot You are absolutely right!

Comment: $$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[e^{\frac{1}{s}-s}\right](t)=-\frac{\sqrt{1-t} J_1\left(2 \sqrt{1-t}\right) \theta (-1+t)}{-1+t}$$

Answer (score 3):

It works just fine

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[(1 - s) (1 + 1/s), s, x]
```

> 1-δ′(x)

```
LaplaceTransform[%, x, s]
```

> 1/s - s

Comment: Sorry the right function is above